# Modal Popup not Closing if multiple Modals are present

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

**I have three different controllers and views**

From Screen when button is clicked Modal1 opens

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'abc.html',
    controller: 'abcCtrl',
    size: 'lg',
    scope: $scope,
});
```

In modal1 there is next button so on Click of Next Button Want to close Modal1 and open Modal2

```
$scope.validate = function(isValid) {
    if (!isValid) {
        $scope.errors = 'Please fill-up required fields';
    } else {
        $scope.errors = '';
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Payment.html',
            controller: 'PaymentCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
            scope: $scope,
        });
    }
};
```

In modal2 there is next button so on Click of Next Button Want to close Modal2 and open Modal3

```
$scope.placeOrder = function() {
        $scope.cart.abc().then(function(result) {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'orderSummary.html',
                    controller: 'SummaryCtrl',
                    size: 'lg',
                    scope: $scope,
                    resolve: {
                        items: function() {
                            return result.data;
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            function(err) {
                //error msg
            });
};
```

If I add $modalInstance.close to Modal1
while Opening another modal that is Modal2, Modal1 is Closed and Modal2 is Opened But none of the buttons work. Modal3 doesnt get opened Don't Know the actual issue what is happening.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of a modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Main Controller First Open Your Modal1,on Close of Modal1 i.e

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'abc',
                controller: 'abcCtrl',
                size: 'lg',
                scope: $scope,
             });

            modalInstance.result.then(function(result) {
                  $scope.def();
              }, function(err) {
                //
            });

  $scope.def = function(){
     //open another 
    }
```

call another function and in that function open another modal and similarly you can do.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are looking for wizard...

have a look [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router)